# If author/screen_name

Tags: conditionals

I have a list of channel entries written by different authors.

How can I create a conditional to display a link if it is a certain author?

For example I want to display a link to a specific author's Twitter account.

So: if screen_name = Bob Smith then Link

Any help appreciated!

N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you've already answered your own question:

```
{if screen_name=='Bob Smith'}link{/if}
```

Comment: Though I would suggest checking based on `author_id`, in case Bob Smith changes his screen name. `{if author_id == "XX"}<!-- insert Twitter code -->{/if}`.

Comment: works perfectly. I should learn to trust my instinct! :)